# Easiest way to connect Docker container to local host

Tags: docker, networking, virtualization

I am wondering if is it possible to connect to an app on local host from Docker container.

I run two Docker container which are connected to each other via `link` option. But how can I connect one of the containers to the local host?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `docker run --network=container:<container-id>`

> --network='container:': reuse another container's network stack

This let you run a container sharing the same network interface (then localhost) from another container.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `host` mode to give your containers the same network ips that the host has (including localhost). `docker run --network=host`:

> --network= 'host': use the Docker host network stack

Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#name-name

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to do the same without `--network` option?

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? `--network=container` won't allow a container to connect to the host...?

Comment: @johnharris85 What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible. 
Try communicate with the host's`<ip:port>`

*ip*: use`ip addr`or something similar to get the one of eth0，not the one of docker0

*port*：the one you assigned to the app

To make the process easier，perhaps turn selinux and firewall down when you try.