# Using Docker Compose / Dockerfile to Connect from Container to Host in Local Development Machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, docker-compose, .net-4.0, docker-for-windows

I have an ASP.Net MVC web application (.Net Framework 4.6) that I usually ran in local dev machine (let's say it's running on `localhost:10000`). The application connect to few local services:

- Database
- Azure Storage (emulator)
- Azure Cosmos (emulator)

Local dev machine (the host) is running on Windows 10.

### Question

I'm in the process of moving this application to a Docker container and was able to run the application off of a Docker container.
My question is, how do I configure the network in (using Docker Compose or `docker run` so that the application (that's in the the container) can connect to the services (database, storage and cosmos emulator) that are in my host?

### What I have tried

- Use `host.docker.internal`

  - [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)
- Docker compose default network

  - https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network
- Docker compose (`network_mode: host`)

  - https://forums.docker.com/t/option-network-mode-host-in-docker-compose-file-not-working-as-expected/51682
- Docker CLI (`run --network`)

  - [Easiest way to connect Docker container to local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45045741/easiest-way-to-connect-docker-container-to-local-host)
- SQL Server to listen to all ports

  - https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2017/9/24/how-to-connect-to-your-local-sql-server-from-inside-docker

None of these work. I still get error when connecting from Container to Host.

### Error

[image]

### Other Configurations

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using `Dockerfile` and Docker Compose yml files to build and run the container locally.

`Dockerfile` file

```
# escape=`

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything else and build app
COPY Web/Web/. ./Web/Web/

# Build the projects
WORKDIR /app/Web/Web
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

# Configure website
SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]

# Install ASP.NET
RUN Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45
EXPOSE 10000
RUN Remove-Website -Name 'Default Web Site'; `
    New-Website -Name 'Web' `
                -Port 10000 -PhysicalPath 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot' `
                -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'

# Final copy for build
COPY --from=build /app/Web/. ./
```

Docker Compose yml file.

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
```

Comment: `host.docker.internal` should work.  Have you tried entering a running container to the command line (powershell) and then trying to debug the issue (using tools like ping, tracert, etc)?

Comment: @phansen great question. At one point, I was able to ping it from a command line. But this doesn't seem to work in ASP.NET MVC application itself

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this gets you all the way there, but maybe you could try co-locating all of those services inside a single Docker Compose file. As long as they're then all running on one `docker-compose up` command, I believe you should be able to reference the service names as the hosts in the other services.

For example, I maintain a collection of DC files for spinning up local databases. In each of those files, the service is named `db` so the host would be http://db:PORT.

https://github.com/alexmacarthur/local-docker-db

It's been a minute since I've toyed with a setup like this... but hopefully it helps point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

On linux I use VSCode development container (docker container).

And if I want to connect from the container to some service run on the host I use `172.17.0.1` instead of localhost.

`172.17.0.1` is the IP address of the gateway between the Docker host.

You can use ifconfig in container to check that you have save network.

```
$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.17.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.25
```

here you can see that my container has IP `172.17.0.2` so the host has IP `172.17.0.1` in the same subnet.